# How to find the tension of $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-physics

[image]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddnkf.jpg))

I want to find the tension of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Also researched something on internet before posting this question. I had found that

$$
T_1 =  T_2  \frac {\cos(30)}{\cos(30)} = m \cdot 9.8 \, \text{m}/\text{s}^2
$$

My Kindest Regards!

Comment: Any hints? I'm still thinking on it.

Comment: It seems to be newton's second law $mg-T_1\cos30=m\times0$ assuming the ball in equilibrium. The side rope would contribute no force vertically. Its hard to tell from just the picture.

Comment: This is a physics problem,branch classical mechanics. But looks more of the variety which is given to mechanical or construction engineers. Can you tell more about the problem? Is that a pendulum? What is the difference between configuration "mass $m$ at $A$" and "mass $m$ at $B$"? Is the mass $m$ attached to the wall at $C$ somehow?

Comment: @Karl Yes. However, I sitll don't have any idea about it. The object is in equilbrium at $C$ with $0$ instant speed. Then the rope $C$ is being cut.

Comment: @mvw I don't think it is pendulum. While the rope is in equilbrium with two rope, the tension of the rope $AK$ is $T_1$. Then, the rope $AC$ has been released. The instant speed of the rope is 0 while returning from point $B$ .

Comment: Is the rope light and extensible

Comment: @Karl That's not given If it is extensible or not.

Comment: @Hamilton Your acceptance of Aretino's answers confirms this is a pendulum first fixed at CA and then released. Just what I asked you in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tension $\vec T_1$ is the easy one, because we have a static balance of forces:
$$
\vec T+\vec T_1+m\vec g=0.
$$
From the vertical components one then gets (I'm using the same letters without arrows to denote the magnitudes of vectors, as it is customary in kinematics):
$$
T_1\cos30°=mg,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
T_1={2mg\over\sqrt3}.
$$
Tension $\vec T_2$, instead, takes place at a time when the mass is moving: even if its velocity vanishes at $B$, its acceleration $\vec a$ is not vanishing and is constrained by kinematics to be perpendicular to $\vec T_2$. We have of course 
$$\vec T_2+m\vec g=m\vec a,$$ 
and separating the components of this equation we get:
$$
T_2\sin30°=ma\cos30°
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
mg-T_2\cos30°=ma\sin30°.
$$
From these equations you can solve for $a$ and $T_2$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still do no not understand the problem. But let us try to start anyway and discuss further.

With $m$ at rest at $A$ we have a force equilibrium
$$
0 = F_G + T_1 + T_{AC}
$$
In $x$-direction it is
$$
0 = 0 + \lVert T_1 \rVert \sin(30^\circ) - \lVert T_{AC} \rVert
$$
and in $y$-direction
$$
0 = -mg+ \lVert T_1 \rVert \cos(30^\circ) + 0
$$
so
$$
\lVert T_1 \rVert = \frac{mg}{\cos(30^\circ)}
$$
and
$$
T_1 =
\frac{mg}{\cos(30^\circ)}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin(30^\circ) \\
\cos(30^\circ)
\end{pmatrix}
=
mg
\begin{pmatrix}
\tan(30^\circ) \\
\cos^2(30^\circ)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Update:** (After the problem was clarified)

So we have a pendulum. First fixed at $CA$ and then released.

At point $B$ we have the force equilibrium
\begin{align}
m \ddot{r} &= F_G + T_2 \iff \\
m \lVert \ddot{r} \rVert
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos(30^\circ) \\
-\sin(30^\circ)
\end{pmatrix}
&=
m
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-g
\end{pmatrix}
+
\lVert T_2 \rVert 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin(30^\circ) \\
\cos(30^\circ)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This gives
$$
\lVert \ddot{r} \rVert = \lVert T_2 \rVert \frac{\tan(30^\circ)}{m} \\
$$
and
$$
-\lVert T_2 \rVert \tan(30^\circ) \sin(30^\circ) = 
-m g + \lVert T_2 \rVert \cos(30^\circ) \iff \\ 
\lVert T_2 \rVert = \frac{mg}{\cos(30^\circ) + \tan(30^\circ)\sin(30^\circ)}
= mg\cos(30^\circ)
$$
which finally gives
$$
T_2 = 
mg \cos(30^\circ)
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin(30^\circ) \\
\cos(30^\circ)
\end{pmatrix}
=
mg
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos(30^\circ) \sin(30^\circ) \\
\cos^2(30^\circ)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equal in the $y$-component, but not in the $x$-component. Aside from the direction the $T_1$ $x$-component is larger.